# UserDir example

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I using ubuntu, nginx, php, mysql.

I want to UserDir http://example.com/~userID

I edit vi nginx default file

```
location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
}
```

i don't understand these line...

```
location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$

alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
```

What is mean `~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$`?

What is mean `$1, $2`?

Comment: Your link doesn't go anywhere useful. Did you copy it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ - case sensitive matching
where url starts (^) with slash and tilde (/~) then parenthesis dot (.) any symbol with one or more occurrences (+) which can or can not be, whatever (?), closing parenthesis, that was match $1, then $2 is next parenthesis matching slash (/), any symbol (.) with zero or many occurrences which can easily not exist (?) and ends ($)

so if url looks like `www.example.com/~tengiz/qw123` , $1 will be equal "~tengiz" and $2 is "/qw123"
and expression should actually look like this I assume:

```
^\/~(.+?)\/(.*)?$
```